# File Manipulation in UNIX - Creating duplicate records based on the count from a column and manipulating only one column

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have a space delimited file.txt with n number of columns. 3rd column in the file.txt is comma delimited, and I want to create duplicate records in same file.txt based on the number of counts in column(n=3) by splitting the comma delimited column with each value.

--file.txt

I have 0,1,2,3 apples

I have 2,3 bananas

I have 3 oranges

--desiredoutput.txt

I have 0 apples

I have 1 apples

I have 2 apples

I have 3 apples

I have 2 bananas

I have 3 bananas

I have 3 oranges

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '$3~/,/{ 
         split($3, a, ","); f=$1 OFS $2; sub(/^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+/,"");
         for (i in a) print f,a[i] $0; next 
     }1' file
```

The output:

```
I have 0 apples
I have 1 apples
I have 2 apples
I have 3 apples

I have 2 bananas
I have 3 bananas

I have 3 oranges
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. What if the file has inconsistent number of columns but the 3rd row is always a comma delimited? Below command will only work if there is only 4 columns.

print $1,$2,a[i],$4